# Can you use the tac command in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, cat

I'm trying to search a large file in reverse order from the command line (using terminal). I found the tac command: http://clifgriffin.com/2008/11/25/tac-and-reverse-grep/

tac is the inverse of cat.  However, when I try to use the tac command in terminal, it says that command doesn't exist.  Is there a way I'd be able to use tac in terminal? What are some other fast ways to search a file from the end via the command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal"? Do you mean "xterm" or do you mean the command line interface that MS provides or do you mean something else?

Comment: @user: I'm guessing he's talking about the MacOS Terminal application.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The MacOs version of `tail` support the `-r` ("reverse") option, and defaults
to displaying the entire file from the end.  So `tail -r filename` should be
exactly equivalent to `tac filename`.

Or, you could try building tac yourself from the source code. It's part of the GNU [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html) package.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy using [OSX Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install coreutils
```

Then it's available as `gtac` (as in GNU tac), for example:

```
# Find and parallel copy all files in reverse order
find . -print | gtac | parallel copy "{}" destination/
```