# Reverse print result of unix find without sort

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I want to sort the result of the find as follows:

I am using:

```
find . -type f -print0
```

Result is:

```
/mnt/sdcard/qu/led/t1/temp42.txt
/mnt/sdcard/qu/led/File.plist
/mnt/sdcard/qu/yellow.plist
/mnt/sdcard/SHA1Keys/SHA1SUMS
/mnt/sdcard/File.xml
/mnt/sdcard/File.plist
/mnt/sdcard/.DS_Store
```

But i want the result as:

```
/mnt/sdcard/.DS_Store
/mnt/sdcard/File.plist
/mnt/sdcard/File.xml
/mnt/sdcard/SHA1Keys/SHA1SUMS
/mnt/sdcard/qu/yellow.plist
/mnt/sdcard/qu/led/File.plist
/mnt/sdcard/qu/led/t1/temp42.txt
```

And if i do:

```
find . -type f print0 | sort -r
```

The order gets all messed up. I saw this solution somewhere:

```
find . -type f -ls | awk '{print $(NF-3), $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

But I can't use it since it prints the results.

Also note I don't have permissions to write to the filesystem, so writing to a file and reversing the lines is not an option.

Comment: Output of `find` is already sorted. You just need print reverse using `tac`

Comment: This question belongs on Super User not Stack Overflow IMHO.

Comment: Are you using `-print` or `-print0`? Your output suggests `-print`.

Comment: @jkshah The output of `find` is NOT *sorted* in any specific way. They look like they are in reverse alphabetical order here, but that is just a coincidence. The order of the output of `find` depends on how the files are stored internally by the filesystem.

Answer (score 15):

Use `tac` (`cat` backwards) to reverse output. You don't need to sort it in reverse order, you just need it reversed.

```
find . -type f | tac
```

If you want to keep the `-print0` then use:

```
find . -type f -print0 | tac -rs '\0'
```

Comment: While this will reverse the order, it will not output the files in any specific order. The order of the output of `find` depends on how the files are stored internally by the filesystem.

Comment: On OSX you can get tac via [homebrew](http://brew.sh) by installing `coreutils` - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32434423/181664

Comment: For me, this answer does not work for files containing a `0` in their filename.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `tail -r`:

```
find . -type f | tail -r
```

Comment: This works only on BSD systems like Mac, not with GNU `tail`.